# How to link one page to another by hyperlink in Django?

Tags: html, web-deployment

I want to create a Home page through which I could go to the other pages that I have created. Suppose I have a home page in which I have two options:

Now, from this home page by click onto the **My work** option I want to go to another page where I have the information related to my work, how can I do so?

**My home page HTML is:**

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %} <h1>Home Page</h1>
 <ul>
     <li>My Achievements</li>
     <li> My Work</li> </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

**The base.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html>
<head> </head>
 <body>
 {% block content %}
 {% endblock %}
 </body> </html>
```

Comment: You should use <a> tag creating hyperlinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest taking a look at one of a number of tutorials for getting started with web development using Django.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/tutorial01/
or 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/skeleton_website These should help you more deeply understand what you're asking as a question, and the technologies you're using. I'd also recommend browsing [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) to learn a bit more about HTML itself and the various tags usable in it.

To more directly answer your question, the `<a>` tag mentioned by Abhijith is what's used to create a reference between pages.